# Check if string equals (at least the first 2 letters) and containing a number

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I've a list with some Strings, want to compare the strings and save the matching strings in a new list.

Matching means, that:

- the first 2 characters have to be letters
- the letters (at least the first 2 letters) have to be equal
- and it have to appear a number after the equal letters

---

```
List<String> items = new List<string>()
    {
        "ne1234",
        "ne2abc",
        "type",
        "12345"
        "12346"
        "s0",
        "s1",
        "numb4er",
        "numb5er",
        "numb8er",
        "tax1-0",
        "tax1-1"
    };

List<String> equalitems = new List<string>();
```

---

Content of `equalitems`

- ne*
- numb*
- tax*

I can't find a good approach to solve this. Has somebody an idea?

Comment: You know that **ne1234** has only **two** letters?

Comment: @xanatos you're right, sry, my fault, fixed

Comment: Your question reads more like a programming *task* than a programming *problem*. It would help if you tell us what you've tried and be specific about where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^\p{L}{2,}(?=\d)");
var grouped = items.GroupBy(x => rx.Match(x).ToString())
                   .Where(x => x.Key != String.Empty)
                   .ToArray();
```

This will use a regular expression to "extract" the initial letters (and check if there is a digit after the letters) and then group by this key. In the end it "filters out" the groups that have an empty key (so a key that doesn't follow the rules you put out)

Note that as written it's a collection of collections (each "matching group" is in a separate collection)

If you want all the matching items together:

```
var allTogether = items.GroupBy(x => rx.Match(x).ToString())
                       .Where(x => x.Key != String.Empty)
                       .SelectMany(x => x)
                       .ToArray();
```

Note that as written for "letter" I used "Unicode" letters (so even àéèìòù and non-english letters, like arabic), and for digits I used "Unicode" digits.

if you want "standard" letters and digits:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]{2,}(?=[0-9])");
```

As written, single elements that don't match anything else (`xxxxxx9`) are put in a group and returned. Add

```
.Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
```

after the

```
.Where(x => x.Key != String.Empty)
```

to filter out these items.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique is to use a custom comparer that implements `IEqualityComparer<string>`.

The comparer looks like this:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
    }

    public string GetStringForHash(string x)
    {
        StringBuilder hashString = new StringBuilder();

        if (x.Length > 2 && x.Substring(0, 2).All(v => char.IsLetter(v)))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsLetter(x[i]))
                {
                    hashString.Append(x[i]);
                }
                else if (char.IsDigit(x[i]))
                {
                    return hashString.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return x;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string x)
    {
        return GetStringForHash(x).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And the implementation looks like this

```
List<String> items = new List<string>()
    {
    "ne1234",
    "ne2abc",
    "type",
    "12345",
    "12346",
    "s0",
    "s1",
    "numb4er",
    "numb5er",
    "numb8er",
    "tax1-0",
    "tax1-1"
};

var comparer = new MyComparer();
var results = items.GroupBy(v => comparer.GetStringForHash(v), comparer).Where(v => v.Count() > 1);

List<String> equalitems = results.SelectMany(v => v).ToList();
```

Since @xanatos made the perfect regex, here is an alternate version of GetStringForHash that uses that regex

```
public string GetStringForHash(string x)
{
    var rx = new Regex(@"^\p{L}{2,}(?=\d)");

    var match = rx.Match(x);

    return match.Success ? match.ToString() : x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have quite an interesting idea :)

First create character sets:

```
    private static char[] chars = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    private static char[] nums = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };
```

Then create an extension method to strimg characters starting from a numeric character (We will use it later):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string RemoveAfterNumber(this string str)
    {
        int ix = str.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
        if (ix >= 0)
        {
            return str.Substring(0, ix);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then follow this code :

```
// Filter string which have non-numeric characters for the the first two letters (Condition 1)
List<String> pass1 = items.Where(x => x.Length > 2 && x.Substring(0, 2).ToCharArray().Intersect(chars).Count() == 2).ToList();

// Get distinct two non-numeric character startings
List<string> pass2 = pass1.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(0, 2)).Where(c => c.Count() > 1).Select(s => s.Key).ToList();

// Get all records starting with these letters
List<string> pass3a = items.Where(x => pass2.Contains(x.Substring(0, 2))).Select(x => x).ToList();

// Remove characters after the first occurance of a numeric character from all records having at least one  numeric character and satisfying the Condition 1. This is also where e use the Extension method.
List<string> pass3b = pass3a.Where(x => x.RemoveAfterNumber() != null).Select(x => x.RemoveAfterNumber()).ToList();

// Group by the repetitions and format as you require
List<string> result = pass3b.Select(x => x + "*").Distinct().ToList();
```

I don't claim this is either the best solution, or the most logical one. But it was quite fun to code it :)